# Does a catch block catch already catched exceptions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch

```
try {
    await function1()
    await function2()
    await function3().catch(err => { /*...*/ })
} catch (err) { /*...*/ }
```

My question is, whether the `catch` block catches the exception emitted by `function3`, even if the exception has already been "catched" via `.catch(err => ...)`?

---

If the `catch` block catches the exception from `function3`, my question if how to prevent this behavior?

My goal is basically to catch specific exceptions of those functions and use the `catch` block for every not handled exception.

Comment: The method that throws an exception will go to the closest exception catch block.

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: That async's catch returns a `Promise`. And `await` is for async function, instead of Promise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once an error is "caught," it won't propagate up. You'll need to throw something after you've caught the error once if you want it to go up any further. Something like:

```
try {
  await function1();
  await function2();
  await function3().catch(err => {
    function3ErrorHandler(err);
    throw err;
  });
} catch (err) {
  generalErrorHandler(err);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The catch block in your outer method will not catch the exception thrown from `function3`, if it is already catched within `fuction3`.

Answer (score 1):

[image: logic behind the try catch]

It will trigger first:

```
await function3().catch(err => { /*...*/ })
```

Before triggering:

```
} catch (err) { /*...*/ }
```